# Custom authentication middleware in Blazor - how to see if request is anonymous page?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to write my own authentication code.

In good old HttpModules, I could use "OnAuthenticateRequest" when a "Authorize" page was requested.

My middleware code is something like this:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    }
}
```

... but that will check all requests.

How can I from my middleware check if the Blazor page @atrribute is AllowAnonymous or Authorize?

I need to be able to do something like...

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (PageIsAuthorize && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    }
    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since it is a front-end application, you'd need to do authorization on the API side, and then for user convenience not show the buttons they can't use anyway.

Comment: Actually the browser navigation in Blazor doesn't make an HTTP request because it's an SPA application. So you cannot check that in a server side middleware. In Blazor server-side it will make a SignalR method call but the request is already opened.

Comment: Thank you guys ... I learned something today. Think I will try aspnet core, but I have same issue there - so I created a new stackowerflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088988/custom-authentication-middleware-how-to-see-if-request-is-anonymous-page