# Custom authentication middleware - how to check if request is anonymous or authorize?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to write my own authentication middleware code.

In good old HttpModules, I could use "OnAuthenticateRequest" when a "Authorize" page was requested.

My middleware code is something like this:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    }
}
```

... but that will also check IsAuthenticated on requests with [AllowAnonymous] attribute.

How can I from my middleware, check if the request has attribute [AllowAnonymous] or [Authorize]?

I need to be able to do something like...

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (HasAuthorizeAttribute && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    }
    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

There is a way to check, from inside your middleware, if the request is targeting a page marked as [Anonymous].

```
//inside your middleware
var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>() is object)
{
    await _next(context);
    return;
}
```

Original solution found on this blog: [Anonymous Aware Middleware](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/anonymous-aware-middleware-with-endpoint-routing-and-healthchecks)

Comment: When combining this with `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, `endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>()` is still always null. Is this still valid in .NET Core 5.x?

Comment: Not working in .Net 6.0

Comment: In Net 6.0, you can check for [Authorize] using (context.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<AuthorizeAttribute>() is object)

Comment: Actually we can use `endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>()` in .NET 6 since we make sure that in Startup the `app.UseRouting();` is used before the `app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();`.

Comment: Is there anything similar for a WA Blazor client. (SPA) ?

Comment: What is the benefit here of using `is object` instead of  `!= null`?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett none, I believe... would need to test...

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, the context.GetEndpoint() method is used to retrieve information about the currently executing endpoint. This includes the route template, HTTP method, and any associated metadata.

Here's an example of how you can use the context.GetEndpoint() method to check if an API method has the Authorize attribute applied:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
   var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
   if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<AuthorizeAttribute>() != null)
   {
       .........          

   }
   else
   {
     ......
   }

   await _next(context);
}
```

Furthermore, you have the option to create a custom attribute/filter and employ it in a similar manner:

```
       var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
       if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<MyCustomAttribute>() != null)
       {
          .........
       }
       else
       {
         ......
       }

       await _next(context);
```

Answer (score -5):

If I understand you mean correctly, you're looking for something like this: You want to classify some action(s) in the controller, some action can be executed after authorization, and otherwise.

In this case, you can set `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` on the top of that actions:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // all of codes here can be executed with unauthorized request(s).
        // code goes here...
    }

    [Authorized]
    public async Task Invoke_2(HttpContext context)
    {
        // all of codes here can be executed WHEN the request is authorized
        // code goes here...
    }
}
```

And, if you want to authorize all of the requests that will hit the controller, you can set the `[Authorize]` attribute on the top of the controller name:

```cs
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // this attribute is still required when you allow anonymous request(s)
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // all of codes here can be executed with unauthorized request(s).
        // code goes here...
    }

    // you can remove [Authorize] attribute from this action, because
    // it's authorized by default
    public async Task Invoke_2(HttpContext context)
    {
        // all of codes here can be executed WHEN the request is authorized
        // code goes here...
    }
}
```

**Note:** Because you're working with `Task`, it's better if you name your action that ends with `Async`, such as: `InvokeAsync` or `Invoke_2Async`.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question which is specifically about ASP.NET MVC Middleware and detecting if a request is for an endpoint with the AllowAnonymous attribute.